# Solve this inequality by an algebraic way, not a geometrical one.

Tags: inequality

$\sqrt{3x+4} > 2|x-1| -x$

Is there any thorough way to solve this inequality with no geometry or drawing their functions?

Comment: If $x<1$, you know $|x-1|=1-x$ and you can solve without absolute value. If $x\ge1$, you know $|x-1|=x-1$ and again you can solve without absolute value. Does that help?

Comment: Well I think your inequality fails to holds at $x=8$. and fails for all $x>7$.

Comment: @stevekass  but when we do this division, there are intervals which make the right part of inequality negative so it's true and we don't need to solve it because always a positive number is greater than a negative one. I'm sorry if i'm not clear enough:(

Comment: If you assume $x\ge1$ and find some solutions less than $1$, you ignore them. For example, if you try to solve $|x-1|=-2$ this way, you would find solutions for both cases but would discard them because they don’t fit into the assumptions of the case.

Comment: "Geometry" and drawing the functions are tools used in solving which enable us to isolate cases - but critical points can be determined in other ways. For example you need that $3x+4\ge 0$ for the square root to make sense, and $|x-1|$ has a critical point at $x=1$ where we change from $|x-1|=1-x$ to $|x-1|=x-1$.

Answer (score 2):

We must have $x \geq -4/3$ in consideration of the domain of the square root function.

You then have to break it up into cases.

**Case 1**: Assume $-4/3 \leq x \leq 1$

Then

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3x+4} > 2|x-1|-x &= 2(1-x)-x = 2-3x \\
&\Updownarrow \\
3x+4+\sqrt{3x+4}-6 &> 0 
\end{align*}

Make the substitution $u = 3x+4$ and complete the square

\begin{align*}
u+\sqrt{u}-6 &> 0 \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\left(\sqrt{u}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} = u+\sqrt{u}+\frac{1}{4} &> \frac{25}{4} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\sqrt{u}+\frac{1}{2} > \frac{5}{2} \hspace{10pt} &\text{or} \hspace{10pt} \sqrt{u}+\frac{1}{2} < -\frac{5}{2} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\sqrt{u} > 2 \hspace{10pt} &\text{or} \hspace{10pt} \sqrt{u} < -3
\end{align*}

The latter inequality has no solutions. So we just need to solve

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3x+4} &= \sqrt{u} > 2 \\
&\Updownarrow \\
3x+4 &> 4 \\
&\Updownarrow \\
x &> 0
\end{align*}

But recall we made the assumption that $x \leq 1$ at the beginning. So this case gives the solutions $0 < x \leq 1$.

I'll let you carry out the analysis for the $x \geq 1$ case on your own.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it must be that $\;x\ge-\cfrac43\;$ , so  $\;\left[-\frac43,\infty\right)\;$ is the inequality's definition domain.

Second,  the inequality is trivial if the right side is non-positive, and this hapens if:

$$x-1<0\iff -\frac43\le x<1\implies-2(x-1)\le x\implies 3x\ge2\implies x\ge\frac23\implies \left[\frac23,\,1\right]$$

and for $\;x\ge 1\;$ we get $\;2(x-1)\le x\implies 1\le x\le2\;$

So we already have trivial solution if $\;x\in\left[\frac23,\,2\right]\;$

Thus, we can now assume the right side is positive, and we can square both sides, getting:

$$3x+4\ge4(x-1)^2-4x|x-1|+x^2\implies 5x^2-11x-4x|x-1|\le0\iff$$

$$x\left(5x-11-4|x-1|\right)\le0$$

and again we take two cases:

$$x<1\implies x\left(5x-11+4(x-1)\right)\le0\iff x\left(9x-15\right)\le0\iff$$

$$\iff0\le x\le\frac{15}9\implies x\in[0,1)$$

and

$$x\ge1\implies x\left(5x-11-4(x-1)\right)\le0\iff x(x-7)\le0\iff 0\le x\le7\implies\left[1,\,7\right]$$

So the final solution is $\;[0,\,7]\;$ .